# Can't figure out why arithmetic parameters are not being passed

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Buttons</title>
<style type="text/css">

.intro{background-color:;}
.duction{background-color:blue;}
.function{background-color:grey;}
.equals{background-color:orange;}
</style>





</head>
<body>
<form name="calculator">
<input type="text"  name="display" length="50" width="100">
<div>
<input type= "button" value="7" class="intro" id="7" onclick="one(7)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="8" class="intro" id="8" onclick="one(8)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="9" class="intro" id="9" onclick="one(9)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="+" class="intro" id="+" onclick="one(+)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="-" class="intro" id="-" onclick="one(-)"></button>
<div>
<input type= "button" value="4" class="intro" id="4" onclick="one(4)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="5" class="intro" id="5" onclick="one(5)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="6" class="intro" id="6" onclick="one(6)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="x" class="intro" id="x" onclick="one(*)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="/" class="intro" id="/" onclick="one(/)"></button>
<div>
<input type= "button" value="1" class="intro" id="1" onclick="one(1)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="2" class="intro" id="2" onclick="one(2)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="3" class="intro" id="3" onclick="one(3)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="=" class="intro" id="=" onclick="Evaluate()"></button>
<div>
<input type= "button" value="0" class="intro" id="0" onclick="one(0)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="." class="intro" id="." onclick="one(.)"></button>
<input type= "button" value="c" class="intro" onclick="clearDigit()"></button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\LS\Desktop\QBJS\button.js">



</script>



</body>
</html>


var timer;
var object;
var thing;
var digit="";
var result;


function one(event)
{
   clearTimeout(timer);
   timer=setTimeout(function(){AddDigit(event);},200);

}
```

in this function I started off using a regEx to check for digits and arithmetic operators being passed into x. Thats when I realized that my arithmetic operators were not being passed at all. I don't know why!!!

```
function AddDigit(x)
{
   alert(x);
   /*if(/^\d[+-*\/$/.test(x)) 

       {document.calculator.display.value+=x;}
   else 


      */ {document.calculator.display.value+=digit + x;}
}



 function Evaluate()
{
  result=eval(document.calculator.display.value);
  document.calculator.display.value = result;
}



document.ondblclick=function(button)
{
   clearTimeout(timer);

   thing=button.target;

   if(thing.className=="intro")
      {thing.className="duction";}

   else if(thing.className=="duction")
      {thing.className="intro";}    
}



function clearDigit()
{
   document.calculator.display.value="";
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as arithmetic parameter. It must be one of the valid data types.

Comment: @Jay How would I change the parameters to valid data types?

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that `one(+)` is not valid Javascript.  Try this:

```
<input type= "button" value="+" class="intro" id="+" onclick="one('+')">
```

Same for your other operator buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

Start with valid HTML, all those closing `</button>` tags are invalid and there is no closing tag for the form. Most of the ID values are invalid, though it really doesn't matter much, you don't need them anyway.

Consider putting a single click listener on the form, then respond to whatever element the event was dispatched from.

As an example, below is a very basic calculator (it doesn't do any checking that the constructed expression is valid). Note that displayed mathematic symbols are different to those used in javascript mathematic expressions so the displayed symbols on the screen are mapped to javascript symbols and stored in a separate input (shown in the example but should be hidden in use).

```
<form onclick="handleClick(this, event);">

  <!-- this input should be type hidden, left visible for demo -->
  <input type="text" name="store">

  <table> 
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3"><input type="text" value="" name="screen" readonly>
      <td><input type="button" value="=" name="bequal">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="7" name="b7">
      <td><input type="button" value="8" name="b8">
      <td><input type="button" value="9" name="b9">
      <td><input type="button" value="&divide;" name="bdiv">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="4" name="b4">
      <td><input type="button" value="5" name="b5">
      <td><input type="button" value="6" name="b6">
      <td><input type="button" value="&times;" name="btimes">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="1" name="b1">
      <td><input type="button" value="2" name="b2">
      <td><input type="button" value="3" name="b3">
      <td><input type="button" value="&minus;" name="bminus">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="button" value="0" name="b0">
      <td><input type="button" value="." name="bpoint">
      <td><input type="reset"  value="C" name="bclear">
      <td><input type="button" value="&plus;" name="bplus">
  </table>
</form>

<script>
function handleClick(form, evt) {

  // Stored symbol for eval is different to displayed symbol
  var buttonMap = {
    '247':'/', '215':'*', '8722':'-', '43':'+'
  }
  var el = evt.target || evt.srcElement;

  if (el.type == 'button') {
    if (el.name == 'bequal') {

      // Update display with result of evaluating expression
      form.screen.value = eval(form.store.value);

      // Update stored value
      form.store.value = form.screen.value;

    } else {
      // Update displayed expression
      form.screen.value += el.value;

      // Update expression to evaluate, map &times; to * and so on.
      form.store.value += buttonMap[el.value.charCodeAt(0)] || el.value;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Please note that this is just a demo, it needs a lot more work to be robust, e.g. to validate the expression to be evaluated (e.g. can't press times then divide) and evaluate each expression when the next symbol is pressed.